# Element Position in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I'm still newbie in using CSS..
I really need help for doing our team's small project for mobile app :D

Here's my question :D
Is it possible for CSS to put "one element" above "another element" ??

For example I have "a wooden board" element and I have another element "sticks" ..
I would like the "stick" element behind "the wooden board" element.. So it's like a billboard style :D
(If in Photoshop, we can just drag the layer "sticks" below the layer "board")

If it is possible, then how to do it ?

I try to look for some sources but didn't get any result..
Any help would be appreciated :D (code/reference/etc)
Thanks a lot

NB : can't post the image :( since I just start to use stackoverflow, sorry :(

Comment: use `z-index`, just note that you also need to set the `position` property of the elements for it to work

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, there are multiple ways of achieving that..

1st using `position: relative;` and `z-index`(optional)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KJXts/)

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>


.one {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #f00;
}

.two {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #0f0;
    position: relative;
    top: -70px;
    left: 30px;
}
```

2nd you can use `position: absolute;` wrapped inside `position: relative;` container

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/KJXts/1/)

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>

.one {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #f00;
    position: relative;
}

.two {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #0f0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    left: 30px;
}
```

The first example is useful if you have 2 separate elements, you can use `position: relative;` and position the element accordingly using `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties.

The other example uses `position: absolute;` but did you see the change in markup? I've positioned `absolute` the `child` element, which is nested inside `position: relative;` element. I would prefer this solution.

`z-index` is optional, say if you want the bring up the 1st element over second

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KJXts/2/)

Make sure you use `position` property which is set to `relative` `absolute` or `fixed` as `z-index` doesn't work on `static` which is default position.

---

Also I would like to add up here, that I didn't provided `z-index` solution for Demo 2 as the elements are nested, so you cannot position a child element behind parent, it inherits parent elements `z-index`